# Implementing the quick sort with median of three

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting, python-3.x, quicksort

I've stumbled upon the quick sort algorithm in "Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structures", by Brad Miller and David Ranum (http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/sorting.html#the-quick-sort).

The quick sort algorithm that is presented there, takes the first value in a list to be a pivot value. Exercise is to modify a program to choose pivot value as median of three. Here's the original script:

```
def quickSort(alist):
   quickSortHelper(alist,0,len(alist)-1)

def quickSortHelper(alist,first,last):
   if first<last:

       splitpoint = partition(alist,first,last)

       quickSortHelper(alist,first,splitpoint-1)
       quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)


def partition(alist,first,last):
   pivotvalue = alist[first]

   leftmark = first+1
   rightmark = last

   done = False
   while not done:

       while leftmark <= rightmark and \
               alist[leftmark] <= pivotvalue:
           leftmark = leftmark + 1

       while alist[rightmark] >= pivotvalue and \
               rightmark >= leftmark:
           rightmark = rightmark -1

       if rightmark < leftmark:
           done = True
       else:
           temp = alist[leftmark]
           alist[leftmark] = alist[rightmark]
           alist[rightmark] = temp

   temp = alist[first]
   alist[first] = alist[rightmark]
   alist[rightmark] = temp


   return rightmark
```

And I modified it a bit, first added `median()` function:

```
def median(data):
    sd = sorted(data)
    N = len(data) - 1
    a = sd[N // 2]
    b = sd[(N + 1) // 2]
    return (a+b) // 2
```

Then, in `partition()` function, modified `pivotvalue` to be:

```
pivotvalue = median([alist[0]] + [alist[len(alist)-1]] + [alist[len(alist)//2]])
```

And changed `leftmark` to start with index `0`, not `1`:

```
leftmark = first
```

Instead of:

```
leftmark = first+1
```

And then changed steps to be executed when finally `done == True`, as to correctly exchange `rightmark` and `pivot` value:

```
temp = pivotvalue
alist[alist.index(pivotvalue)] = alist[rightmark]
alist[rightmark] = temp
```

But when invoked with:

```
alist = [77,26,93,17,54,31,44,55,20]
quickSort(alist)
print(alist)
```

I'm getting the:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/reloader/Templates/Exercises/quick_sort.py", line 52, in <module>
    quickSort(alist)
  File "/home/reloader/Templates/Exercises/quick_sort.py", line 9, in quickSort
    quickSortHelper(alist,0,len(alist)-1)
  File "/home/reloader/Templates/Exercises/quick_sort.py", line 17, in quickSortHelper
    quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)
  File "/home/reloader/Templates/Exercises/quick_sort.py", line 17, in quickSortHelper
    quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)
  File "/home/reloader/Templates/Exercises/quick_sort.py", line 17, in quickSortHelper
    quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)
  File "/home/reloader/Templates/Exercises/quick_sort.py", line 17, in quickSortHelper
    quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)
  File "/home/reloader/Templates/Exercises/quick_sort.py", line 17, in quickSortHelper
    quickSortHelper(alist,splitpoint+1,last)
  File "/home/reloader/Templates/Exercises/quick_sort.py", line 17, in quickSortHelper
  .......
  RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

As I find this algorithm to be a bit complicated (and with a bit too much steps to execute), I really don't know what to change in order for this to work, and what I did broke with my modifications. I just set the pivot value to be value from the middle of the list. Should something else, which I cannot see at the moment, be modified as well?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

If I leave `leftmark`'s initial value to be `firstmark + 1` (that is, index 1 of the list), I'm not getting the infinite recursion error, but the list is not properly sorted as well:

```
[55, 26, 31, 44, 17, 77, 54, 20, 93]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pick the median from the subarray that's being partitioned:

Replace this:

```
pivotvalue = alist[first]
```

with

```
pivotindex = median(alist, first, last, (first + last) // 2)
alist[first], alist[pivotindex] = alist[pivotindex], alist[first]
pivotvalue = alist[first]
```

and the median finder doesn't have to be so convoluted.

```
def median(a, i, j, k):
  if a[i] < a[j]:
    return i if a[k] < a[i] else k if a[k] < a[j] else j
  else:
    return j if a[k] < a[j] else k if a[k] < a[i] else i
```

Comment: I'm still getting into infinite recursion with `leftmark = first` even if I change this.

Comment: If I leave `leftmark = first + 1` list again isn't properly sorted: `[17, 77, 20, 31, 26, 44, 54, 55, 93]`

Comment: @Reloader Okay. I see. They're using a lame version of the Dutch flag algorithm.  You must swap the median to the `first` position to avoid lots of other changes. I fixed my answer.  This is not a very good quicksort code.

Comment: Thank you. I've read similar complaints about some other pieces of code by this authors when posting problems here.

Comment: @Reloader if you want to see the standard better way of partitioning, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_national_flag_problem . For Quicksort, `low` is the pivot, and `high` is `low+1` or - better - change the tests to `< pivot` and `> pivot`.

Comment: How is this median finder correct? Consider input `median([2,3,1], 0, 1, 2)`.